# AutoMapper mapping nested List object does not mapping correctly

Tags: c#, automapper

I need to map DTOs object into my entity object.mapping DTO object into Entity object with one to many relationships it's not working.however when mapping single DTO object to single Entity object its work fine.

Entities -

```
public class EntityClass   
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public decimal MonthlyPricing { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<DynamicField> DynamicFields { get; set; }
}


public class DynamicField
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Service")]
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }

    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

My DTO is below ,

```
public class DTO_Object
{

    public int Id { get; set; }  

    [Required]
    public decimal MonthlyPricing { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<DynamicFieldForm> DynamicFields { get; set; }
}

public class DynamicFieldForm
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
}
```

my mapping is below,

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<DTO_Object, 
EntityClass>().ForMember(s => s.DynamicFields,o => o.MapFrom(s => 
s.DynamicFields.Select(m => m.Id))));

IMapper imapper = config.CreateMapper();

var service = imapper.Map<DTO_Object, EntityClass>(sourse);
```

Comment: What is the AddServiceForm in your MapperConfiguration?

Comment: If you're on the latest version set CreateMissingTypeMaps to false.

Comment: AddServiceForm is DTO object which is needed to map to Entity object

Answer (score 0):

Auto Mapper  is  not  good  habit !  It is  better  that  you  should  build your  DBContext  manually  to link your model's  data  which are/is  encapsulated into  the class  model.

Again  build  your  Entity Context manually  DO NOT USE  AutoMapper it is  a very 
 bad habit  you  can  check out this  on web resources  why is  better  to  write 
 you Entity  context  manually.

If  you want  Entity Data  class  generate  for you  you  can  do  it  Code  First  from  Database  and  when  you  model(s) will  be  created  also Entity DataContext  will  be created in parallel  and with correct mapping  then you  make  correction(Adding Models, Deleting something,  Editing).

P.S. For example  when i am building  something for Enterprise Apps(WebAPI or Web back end) I DO NOT USE AUTO MAPPING.  I  am coding  everything  myself.

Comment: Yes, I got your point.really appreciated.
but in my scenario, i need to use autoMapper :/